# Using variables with GRANT and DENY in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005 how can you use a variable for the username to GRANT or DENY permissions to objects withing the database? I have tried:

```
DECLARE @username varchar(30)
SET @username = 'DOMAIN\UserName'
GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO @username
GRANT UPDATE([field one], [field two], [field three]) ON [mytable] TO @username
```

I get `Incorrect syntax near '@username'`, so then I wrapped it in [ and ]

```
GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO [@username]
```

However this then results in `Cannot find the user '@username', because it does not exist or you do not have permission`. How can I do this without having to type out the username for each statement? I want to do this to reduce chances of any typo's (which could result in the wrong user getting permissions set)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need dynamic sql, change EXEC to PRINT if you want to see what will get executed
added the quotename function because you need brackets around domain users

```
 DECLARE @username varchar(30)
SET @username = 'DOMAIN\UserName'

SET @username = quotename(@username)

exec  ('GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO ' + @username )
exec ('GRANT UPDATE([field one], [field two], [field three]) ON [mytable] TO ' + @username )
```

Comment: That worked fine, thanks. No need for SET @sql statements with this

Answer (score 1):

Will using dynamic SQL work in this case?

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000)
SET @sql = 'GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO ' + @username
EXEC @sql
```

Comment: This causes an error:

Could not find stored procedure 'GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO DOMAIN\UserName'

Comment: you need brackets, see my answer

Comment: SQLMenace mentions the necessary fix: 

SET @sql = 'GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO ' + QUOTENAME(@username)

Answer (score 1):

Updating the answer from [Yoopergeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121366/yoopergeek), you could have

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000)
SET @sql = 'GRANT SELECT ON [mytable] TO [' + Replace(@username, '[', '\[') + ']' + Char(13) + Char(10)
SET @sql = 'GRANT UPDATE([field one], [field two], [field three]) ON [mytable] TO [' + Replace(@username, '[', '\[') + ']'
PRINT @sql
EXEC @sql
```